# Chart.js Bar chart : display labels

Tags: plugins, label, chart.js

I have a bar chart and I use the Labels plugin to display a value above the bars: 'A1', 'B6', 'C15', 'DK0', 'DK1', 'DK2'
I can not display these values.

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            labels: {
                datasets: [{
                        data: ['A1','B6','C15','DK0','DK1','DK2']
                    }],
            }
        },
```

Expected: 'A1','B6','C15','DK0','DK1','DK2'

Actual result : '100%'

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this way?

labels: [‘’, ‘’, ‘’],
datasets: [{ data: [‘’, ‘’, ‘’] backgroundColor: [‘’, ‘’, ‘’] borderColor: [‘’, ‘’, ‘’] }]